# Need to force refresh on a WPF Label

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, label

I am making an **asynchronous** call to a web service. Since it might take a few seconds there is a status Label used to let the user know what's going on. But even though the call is async the first call seems to block for a few seconds and the status label takes too long to get updated. In WinForms I could force the label to refresh (using Update() I think) but not in WPF. Any super easy ways to get this working?

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 1):

You could move the entire call logic into a QueueWorkUserItem or BackgroundWorker block. That way the first proxy initialization would not block the UIThread (before the async. Begin/End pattern kicks in). Assuming that you are using databinding the object exposing the property bound to the Label implemented INotifyPropertyChanged everything should happen automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd (wildly) guess that the blocking is due to the creation/initialization of the service proxy classes.  If so, you could try to create the proxy earlier, or call your asynchronous web service in another thread.

The general answer to your question about refreshing controls... I have always relied on data binding to do this.  That won't help though if the main UI thread is stuck doing something.  And if the UI thread is stuck, I don't know that there's any way to get it to draw.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to tell the label to refresh that will actually work in your case.  If the UI is being blocked, it won't refresh.  Basically, when you actually get to the point where you update the label's text, it will show in WPF.  The only possible exception that I can think to that would be if you are using a non-WPF control but even then it should work.

My suggestion would be to update the label before you perform the first action (even before variables are initialized, since this might be where the issue actually is).  Here is a pseudocode example of what I mean (just in case I wasn't clear):

```
private void KickOffProcess()
{
   label1.Text = "Processing ...";  //This is where you need to move the label update code
   AsyncCall();
}
```